# What is the worst thing that will happen if I do not update iTunes to its latest version?

Tags: itunes, security

Okay, I like iTunes, and it is a wonderful software. I run it on Windows, unfortunately sometimes when I do update to minor version updates, the whole windows panel of iTunes becomes unresponsive and behave oddly. So I have decided to not update for couple of months. Is it wise, or will it have any security loophole in my computer.

Comment: You should be fine, since iTunes has not issued security updates.

Comment: @Tyson, see this for more explanation on the meaning of couple of....http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1427/does-a-couple-always-mean-two

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know this is to watch the release notes for every subsequent version of iTunes and see if the release has any security content.

This will change over time, but the present version of iTunes for Windows is 12.1.2, for which the release notes can be found here: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1614.

You will note that security is not mentioned for this release, but you do need to be aware of future releases so that you can check their notes when they come out to see if any flaws have arose.

You may find it easier instead to just follow some Mac news blogs, since they typically all run stories when an update is released.

Overall, however, I wouldn't say this is a tremendous security risk.